# Does increasing a Heroes stars increase their HQ perks?

Tags: assassins-creed-rebellion

Some of my heroes, such as Gaspar Donozo, has a perk which is active in the HQ.

Does increasing a heroes star level up their hq parks? If not, how do I level the HQ perks?

For example, my Gaspar is currently 2 stars, but his Scholar perk is still level 1 of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skills will increase as you rank a hero up, but not necessarily every rank up.

If you go to a character and then select the skills tab you will see all the characters skills and their current rank. If you then click on the "DETAILS" button you will see a grid showing all the skills along the top and the hero rank down the left.

This shows you visually when a skill will be increased. You can also tap the skill levels to view their effects at that level, allowing you to see what the effects of future levels of skills actually are.